# Nexus: How many artifacts do we have?

Tags: nexus

At work, we have been using Nexus OSS 1.8.0 for a few years now. Recently, I (as a Nexus admin) have been asked how many artifacts are in our instance. It's a very simple question, but I can't for the life of me find an answer anywhere:

- I couldn't find it in Nexus' UI, Google or here;
- Looking at Nexus' REST API, there is a search endpoint ([two](https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-indexer-lucene-plugin/default/docs/rest.lucene.search.html), [actually](https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-indexer-lucene-plugin/default/docs/rest.data_index.html), although **data_index** is now deprecated), which also returns how many results the query yielded (field **totalCount**), except that I haven't figured out how to just search for *everything*: providing an empty parameter yields a 400 response.

I provided a reasonable estimate of many artifacts we have, and that's good enough for now, but I had more work than I felt I should've had... Did anybody have the same problem?

---

**Update:**

I needed to know how many internal artifacts we have (as opposed to external dependencies from Maven Central and the like), so I ended up GET-ing:

`http://<OUR-NEXUS>/service/local/lucene/search?q=*&repositoryId=<OUR-REPO>`

for every hosted repository and adding up the **totalCount** fields.

For the full count, searching for `q=*` yielded too many results, so I ran:

`find $PATH_TO_SONATYPE_HOME | grep sha1 | egrep -v 'nexus-maven-repository-index|repository-metadata|maven-metadata|\.pom\.sha1' | wc -l`

But I'm still surprised this type of information isn't readily available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Mark suggested is ok, but if you count sha1 files instead, you'll get a more accurate count as nexus will create that file on upload of every artifact.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
find $PATH_TO_SONATYPE_HOME -name "*.jar" | wc -l
```

It will only count JAR artfacts but that normally accounts for the bulk of files stored in Nexus